# Complex LINQ to XML query assistance

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I don’t know if the query I am trying to do is even possible but if one of you LINQ to SQL/XML guru’s can figure this out I will be so thankful and salute you as a LINQ God. My end goal is to identify all of the XML Models that are duplicates and show the CECID for all the duplicates except one. So lets say I have an Xdocument that looks like this:

```xml
<ApplianceModels xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ApplianceType="IceMakers">
    <Model>
        <ReferenceNumber>201877149</ReferenceNumber>
        <Action>C</Action>
        <Brand>4564</Brand>
        <ModelNumber>1234212</ModelNumber>
        <EquipmentType>A</EquipmentType>
        <CoolingType>W</CoolingType>
        <IceType>C</IceType>
        <IceMakerProcessType>B</IceMakerProcessType>
        <TestLabCode>ARN3190</TestLabCode>
        <ManufacturerCode>ARN2396</ManufacturerCode>
        <HarvestRateLbs24Hr>56</HarvestRateLbs24Hr>
        <EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>4.00</EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>
        <WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>12</WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>
        <IceHardnessAdjustmentFactor xsi:nil="true" />
        <RegulatoryStatus>I</RegulatoryStatus>
        <CECID>d579ae7a-f3f7-4627-a3f1-f17b23aa28e3</CECID>
    </Model>
    <Model>
        <ReferenceNumber>201877143</ReferenceNumber>
        <Action>C</Action>
        <Brand>4564</Brand>
        <ModelNumber>12342</ModelNumber>
        <EquipmentType>A</EquipmentType>
        <CoolingType>W</CoolingType>
        <IceType>C</IceType>
        <IceMakerProcessType>B</IceMakerProcessType>
        <TestLabCode>ARN3190</TestLabCode>
        <ManufacturerCode>ARN2396</ManufacturerCode>
        <HarvestRateLbs24Hr>56</HarvestRateLbs24Hr>
        <EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>4.00</EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>
        <WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>12</WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>
        <IceHardnessAdjustmentFactor xsi:nil="true" />
        <RegulatoryStatus>I</RegulatoryStatus>
        <CECID>94c6d6e6-5b6a-4f45-a7ff-70a64e50e4e6</CECID>
    </Model>
    <Model>
        <ReferenceNumber>201877152</ReferenceNumber>
        <Action>C</Action>
        <Brand>4564</Brand>
        <ModelNumber>1231114234</ModelNumber>
        <EquipmentType>A</EquipmentType>
        <CoolingType>W</CoolingType>
        <IceType>C</IceType>
        <IceMakerProcessType>C</IceMakerProcessType>
        <TestLabCode>ARN3190</TestLabCode>
        <ManufacturerCode>ARN2396</ManufacturerCode>
        <HarvestRateLbs24Hr>81</HarvestRateLbs24Hr>
        <EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>1.10</EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>
        <WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>12</WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>
        <IceHardnessAdjustmentFactor>4.45</IceHardnessAdjustmentFactor>
        <RegulatoryStatus>I</RegulatoryStatus>
        <CECID>d97a603c-1836-43a3-b564-ab8d1bdec65f</CECID>
    </Model>
</ApplianceModels>
```

Then in SQL Server I have a table called tApplianceTypeColumns that looks like this for a given appliance type:

```
ApplianceTypeID       ApplianceColumnUnique        ApplianceColumnName
10                    0                            ReferenceNumber
10                    1                            Brand
10                    1                            ModelNumber
10                    0                            EquipmentType
10                    0                            CoolingType
10                    0                            IceType
10                    0                            IceMakerProcessType
10                    0                            HarvestRateLbs24Hr
10                    0                            EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs
10                    0                            WaterCons_galPer100lbs
10                    1                            RegulatoryStatus
```

So here is what I started with but I am far from being close:

```
var DupeItems = from m in doc.Descendants("Model").Elements()
                join at in entities.tApplianceTypeColumns on m.Name equals at.ApplianceColumnName
                group m by m.Element(at.ApplianceColumnName).Value into d
                where at.ApplianceTypeID == ApplianceTypeID
```

So really I want to be able to group by Brand, Model Number, and RegulatoryStatus which are the columns in the tApplianceTypeColumns table that have the ApplianceColumnUnique bit column set to true. The number of true bits could vary depending on the ApplianceTypeID I am looking up in that table.

Additionally, I also need to include two elements in the grouping that are never in the tApplianceTypeColumns table and those elements are Action then ManufacturerCode followed by all the other unique elements from the tApplianceTypeColumns in no specific order.

The ApplianceTypeID is a known parameter that will be passed to the query. So for any set of duplicates I need to display the CECID for the 2nd and subsequent duplicates so that I can take those CECID’s and do lookups in other tables to change their status. But this first step is tough. I don’t care which of the duplicates does not get displayed. I just need to display all others except 1. I hope I have explained this well enough.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would really help if you could indent your XML so that the structure is obvious - and is all the information in that XML really necessary for the question? (I'd also split that final paragraph up for the sake of readability.)

Comment: By "indent the XML" I didn't just mean "add a constant number of spaces at the start of each line" - I meant "indent it so that it shows the structure, with more-nested elements being indented further than others".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task can be split into 3 steps:

1. Find the unique columns to group with:

   > So really I want to be able to group by Brand, Model Number, and RegulatoryStatus which are the columns in the tApplianceTypeColumns table that have the ApplianceColumnUnique bit column set to true. **The number of true bits could vary depending on the ApplianceTypeID I am looking up in that table.**
   >   Additionally, **I also need to include two elements in the grouping** that are never in the tApplianceTypeColumns table and those elements are **`Action` then `ManufacturerCode`** followed by all the other unique elements from the tApplianceTypeColumns in no specific order.

   ```
   Enumerable.Concat(
       "Action,ManufacturerCode".Split(','),
       applianceTypeColumns
           .Where(at => at.ApplianceColumnUnique)
           .Select(at => at.ApplianceColumnName)
   );
   ```
2. Group the models by the columns from prevous step:

   We project the column names into the column values of each model

   ```
   applianceModels.GroupBy(
       model => uniqueColumns.Select(columnName => model.Element(columnName)?.Value).ToArray()
   ```

   However, we can't just group by an array of string, so we need to provider a custom IEqualityComparer:

   ```
   new LambdaComparer<string[]>((a, b) => a.SequenceEqual(b), x => x.Aggregate(13, (hash, y) => hash * 7 + y?.GetHashCode() ?? 0))
   ```
3. Aggregate the duplicates:

   ```
   .Select(g => new { g.Key, Duplicates = g.Select(x => x.Element("CECID")?.Value) })
   ```

---

Everything put together:

```
void Main()
{
    const int ApplianceTypeID = 10;

    var applianceModels = GetApplianceModels().XPathSelectElements("Model"); //.Dump();
    var applianceTypeColumns = GetApplianceTypeColumns().Where(x => x.ApplianceTypeID == ApplianceTypeID); //.Dump();

    var uniqueColumns = Enumerable.Concat(
        "Action,ManufacturerCode".Split(','),
        applianceTypeColumns
            .Where(at => at.ApplianceColumnUnique)
            .Select(at => at.ApplianceColumnName)
    );

    var query = applianceModels
        .GroupBy(
            model => uniqueColumns.Select(columnName => model.Element(columnName)?.Value).ToArray(),
            new LambdaComparer<string[]>((a, b) => a.SequenceEqual(b), x => x.Aggregate(13, (hash, y) => hash * 7 + y?.GetHashCode() ?? 0))
        )
        .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
        .Select(g => new { g.Key, Duplicates = g.Select(x => x.Element("CECID")?.Value) });
        //.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
XElement GetApplianceModels()
{
    return XElement.Parse(
@"<ApplianceModels xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" ApplianceType=""IceMakers"">
    <Model>
        <ReferenceNumber>201877149</ReferenceNumber>
        <Action>C</Action>
        <Brand>4564</Brand>
        <ModelNumber>1234212</ModelNumber>
        <EquipmentType>A</EquipmentType>
        <CoolingType>W</CoolingType>
        <IceType>C</IceType>
        <IceMakerProcessType>B</IceMakerProcessType>
        <TestLabCode>ARN3190</TestLabCode>
        <ManufacturerCode>ARN2396</ManufacturerCode>
        <HarvestRateLbs24Hr>56</HarvestRateLbs24Hr>
        <EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>4.00</EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>
        <WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>12</WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>
        <IceHardnessAdjustmentFactor xsi:nil=""true"" />
        <RegulatoryStatus>I</RegulatoryStatus>
        <CECID>d579ae7a-f3f7-4627-a3f1-f17b23aa28e3</CECID>
    </Model>
    <Model>
        <ReferenceNumber>201877143</ReferenceNumber>
        <Action>C</Action>
        <Brand>4564</Brand>
        <ModelNumber>12342</ModelNumber>
        <EquipmentType>A</EquipmentType>
        <CoolingType>W</CoolingType>
        <IceType>C</IceType>
        <IceMakerProcessType>B</IceMakerProcessType>
        <TestLabCode>ARN3190</TestLabCode>
        <ManufacturerCode>ARN2396</ManufacturerCode>
        <HarvestRateLbs24Hr>56</HarvestRateLbs24Hr>
        <EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>4.00</EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>
        <WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>12</WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>
        <IceHardnessAdjustmentFactor xsi:nil=""true"" />
        <RegulatoryStatus>I</RegulatoryStatus>
        <CECID>94c6d6e6-5b6a-4f45-a7ff-70a64e50e4e6</CECID>
    </Model>
    <Model>
        <ReferenceNumber>201877152</ReferenceNumber>
        <Action>C</Action>
        <Brand>4564</Brand>
        <ModelNumber>1231114234</ModelNumber>
        <EquipmentType>A</EquipmentType>
        <CoolingType>W</CoolingType>
        <IceType>C</IceType>
        <IceMakerProcessType>C</IceMakerProcessType>
        <TestLabCode>ARN3190</TestLabCode>
        <ManufacturerCode>ARN2396</ManufacturerCode>
        <HarvestRateLbs24Hr>81</HarvestRateLbs24Hr>
        <EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>1.10</EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs>
        <WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>12</WaterCons_galPer100Lbs>
        <IceHardnessAdjustmentFactor>4.45</IceHardnessAdjustmentFactor>
        <RegulatoryStatus>I</RegulatoryStatus>
        <CECID>d97a603c-1836-43a3-b564-ab8d1bdec65f</CECID>
    </Model>
</ApplianceModels>");
}
IEnumerable<(int ApplianceTypeID, bool ApplianceColumnUnique, string ApplianceColumnName)> GetApplianceTypeColumns()
{
    var data =
@"ApplianceTypeID       ApplianceColumnUnique        ApplianceColumnName
10                    0                            ReferenceNumber
10                    1                            Brand
10                    1                            ModelNumber
10                    0                            EquipmentType
10                    0                            CoolingType
10                    0                            IceType
10                    0                            IceMakerProcessType
10                    0                            HarvestRateLbs24Hr
10                    0                            EnergyCons_kWhPer100Lbs
10                    0                            WaterCons_galPer100lbs
10                    1                            RegulatoryStatus";
    return Regex.Matches(data, @"^(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)", RegexOptions.Multiline)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => 
        (
            /*ApplianceTypeID = */int.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value),
            /*ApplianceColumnUnique = */int.Parse(x.Groups[2].Value) != 0,
            /*ApplianceColumnName = */x.Groups[3].Value
        ));
}

class LambdaComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> equals;
    private readonly Func<T, int> getHashCode;

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equals, Func<T, int> getHashCode)
    {
        this.equals = equals;
        this.getHashCode = getHashCode;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y) => equals(x, y);
    public int GetHashCode(T obj) => getHashCode(obj);
}
```

Comment: I had to make some small changes to this with applianceModels and ApplianceTypeColumns but it seems to work well at identifying the dupes. I just need to write some code to go through and eliminate one of each. That way I will leave behind one of the dupes. Thank you for such a great solution. It won't let me mark as answer. I guess I haven't be on here long enough.

Comment: I just figured out how to mark as answer and did so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code based on Xiaoy312's solution. Thank you again. It works well. I salute you as a LINQ God:

```
private List<string> XMLDuplicatesToEliminate(XDocument doc, Guid ApplianceTypeID)
{
    var entities = new DbContextFactory().MAEDBSEntities;

    var applianceModels = doc.Descendants("Model");
    var applianceTypeColumns =
    (
        from at in entities.tApplianceTypeColumns
        where
            at.ApplianceTypeID == ApplianceTypeID &&
            at.ApplianceColumnUnique == true
        select new { at.ApplianceColumnName }
    ).ToList();

    var uniqueColumns = Enumerable.Concat(
        "Action,ManufacturerCode".Split(','),
        applianceTypeColumns
            .Select(at => at.ApplianceColumnName)
    );

    List<string> DuplicatesToEliminate = new List<string>();
    var duplicates = applianceModels
        .GroupBy(
            model => uniqueColumns.Select(columnName => model.Element(columnName)?.Value).ToArray(),
            new LambdaComparer<string[]>((a, b) => a.SequenceEqual(b), x => x.Aggregate(13, (hash, y) => hash * 7 + y?.GetHashCode() ?? 0)))
        .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
        .Select(g => new { g.Key, Duplicates = g.Select(x => x.Element("CECID")?.Value) })
        .ToList();

    foreach (var duperow in duplicates)
    {
        string firstdupe = duperow.Duplicates.First();
        IEnumerable<string> allbutone = duperow.Duplicates.Where(x => x != firstdupe);
        foreach (string dupeitem in allbutone)
        {
            DuplicatesToEliminate.Add(dupeitem);
        }
    }

    return DuplicatesToEliminate;
}
```

Comment: You can also just simply `return applianceModels.GroupBy(...).Where(...).SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1).Select(x => x.Element("CECID")?.Value)).ToList();`

Comment: wow it is already blazing fast. That new code doing it all on the return will probably cut the time in half instead of 50ms like 25ms. LOL. Thanks a lot Xiaoy312.